# How to DO MYSQL TRIGGER FOR DELETE Entry Before UPDATE

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have an Two table, main table is "Invoice" and sub table is "Invoice_split".
Before update on the "Invoice" table I want to delete the related data on the sub table "Invoice_split" for that I have written the below query But it's not working.

```
"DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_invoice_update 
BEFORE UPDATE ON mac_invoice FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DELETE FROM mac_invoice_split WHERE OLD.invoice_id = id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;"

id => "Invoice" table primary key
invoice_id =>foreign key of "Invoice" in "Invoice_split" table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this

```
  WHERE OLD.id = invoice_id;
```